# find relational values in two column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to extract values in one column based on another column in pandas, 
For example suppose I have 2 columns in dataframe as below

```
>>> check
  child parent
0     b      a
1     c      a
2     d      b
3     e      d
```

Now I want to extract all values in column "child" for value in column "parent"
My initial value can differ for now suppose it is "a" in column "parent"

also length of dataframe might differ.

I tried below but it is not working if there are few more matching values and length of dataframe is more

```
check = pd.read_csv("Book2.csv",encoding='cp1252')


new = (check.loc[check['parent'] == 'a', 'child']).tolist()
len(new)

a=[]
a.append(new)

for i in range(len(new)):
    new[i]
    new1 = (check.loc[check['parent'] == new[i], 'child']).tolist()
    len(new1)
    if(len(new1)>0):
        a.append(new1)
        for i in range(len(new1)):
            new2 = (check.loc[check['parent'] == new1[i], 'child']).tolist()
            if(len(new1)>0):
                a.append(new2)

flat_list = [item for sublist in a for item in sublist]

>>> flat_list
['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
```

Is there any efficient way to get desired results, it will be a great help. Please advice

Comment: Can you share the expected output?

Comment: Can you share the `"Book2.csv"`?

Comment: `df.loc[df.child.isin(df.parent), 'child']`?

Comment: @AmazingThingsAroundYou, Expected output is "flat_list" like if matching values for "a" in parent column from child column, now i have new values b, c I need to search for matching values for "b" and "c" in parent column from child column, this way it might need to search for all values

Comment: @QuangHoang, It is working but I am not getting , how will I use information like value "a" in parent column in solution you shared

Comment: Are you looking for all descendants of `a`?

Comment: @QuangHoang, Yes correct like results should return ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

Comment: This is a [union-find](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) problem. I don't think pandas has a way to do such. Glad to learn otherwise.

Comment: Are you sure? Because, according to the table you put in the question, it should be `['b', 'c']`. `'d'`and `'e'` are `'b'`'s and `'d'`'s descendants, respectively.

Comment: Ah, you mean _all_ descendants, not the direct ones?

Comment: @pmarcol, Yes since "b" and "c" are values in column "child" for "a" in parent , I need to search for child values for "b" and "c" also likewise it will go further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion is a way to do it. Suppose that `check` is your dataframe, define a recursive function:

```
final = [] #empty list which is used to store all results

def getchilds(df, res, value):
    where = df['parent'].isin([value]) #check rows where parent is equal to value
    newvals = list(df['child'].loc[where]) #get the corresponding child values
    if len(newvals) > 0:
        res.extend(newvals)
        for i in newvals: #recursive calls using child values
            getchilds(df, res, i)

getchilds(check, final, 'a')
print(final)
```

`print(final)` prints `['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']` if `check` is your example.

This works if you do not have cyclic calls, like `'b'` is child of `'a'` and `'a'` is child of `'b'`. If this is the case, you need to add further checks  to prevent infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

```
out_dict = {}
for v in pd.unique(check['parent']):
    out_dict[v] = list(pd.unique(check['child'][check['parent']==v]))
```

Then calling `out_dict` prints:

```
{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': ['d'], 'd': ['e']}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me just make a guess and say you want to get all the values of a column child where parent value is **x**

```
import pandas as pd

def get_x_values_of_y(comparison_val, df, val_type="get_parent"):
   val_to_be_found = ["child","parent"][val_type=="get_parent"]
   val_existing = ["child","parent"][val_type != "get_parent"]
   mask_value = df[val_existing] == "a"
   to_be_found_column = df[mask_value][val_to_be_found]
   unique_results = to_be_found_column.unique().tolist()
   return unique_results

check = pd.read_csv("Book2.csv",encoding='cp1252')
# to get results of all parents of child "a"
print get_x_values_of_y("a", check)

# to get results of all children of parent "b"
print get_x_values_of_y("b", check, val_type="get_child")

# to get results of all parents of every child
list_of_all_children = check["child"].unique().tolist()
for each_child in list_of_all_children:
    print get_x_values_of_y(each_child, check)

# to get results of all children of every parent
list_of_all_parents = check["parent"].unique().tolist()
for each_parent in list_of_all_parents:
    print get_x_values_of_y(each_parent, check, val_type= "get_child")
```

Hope this solves your problem.